# Android: how to install a downloaded application from our app similar to a playstore

Tags: java, android, android-intent, web-applications, webview

I have an app which runs Web-View and it's sort of similar to play store. I can download applications with that to a specific folder but I'm not finding any method to install that app by itself by giving permissions of course.
similar to blackmart alpha or 9 apps etc.

Comment: Its not possible natively. You would need root.

Comment: @Dylan But apps like VIDMATE, 9APPS, aptoid does it without root

Answer (score 0):

You can Open an Intent to install the app on download Completed.
But results in a prompt which asks user to install or cancel.

Or

You can execute an adb shell command within your app to install the app silently but you would first have the user to toggle Usb debugging on their phones. But this may result your app to be one linked with security issues and Google Play Store may deal it as Vulnerable and marks it as a Virus.

So deal wisely.